Use of framelayout in Android Studio
My teacher assigned me a homework with Android Studio: create an interface with cards to show information. I'm trying to add a rounded image
My teacher explained me that I must add a framelayout and add inside it two imageview, one that contains the image and the other that has a sort of rounded style. The second imageview must be applied over the first (like a sort of mask). I tried but the result is very bad.  In particular I created two imageview (the imageview with id img_segn contains the image, the imageview with id img_estern is the "mask" with the rounded corners). Can you please help me?
this is the xml code
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img_estern"
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img_segn"
android:layout_width="349dp"
android:layout_height="199dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</FrameLayout>

this is the code of rounded_corners.xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="30dp"/>
<solid android:color="@color/bianco_sfondo"/>
<stroke
android:width="10dp" android:color="@color/black"/>
</shape>

Sorry about formatting but is the first time that I publish something here
